# Party Data Model / Universal Data Model Example

Tags: database-design

I am trying to implement `Party Data Model` / `Universal Data Model` in our application which needs to store different relationships between entities (People, Companies).

Example of relationships: Employer/Employee, Husband/Wife, Seller/Customer.

We also need to store the different types of roles a person can have inside a company.

For example, a person can be Employee at Google, but at the same time occupies a Head of Development position.

I am using [this schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820972/how-to-model-party-relationship-data-in-ofbiz) as an example, but i need to admit that i don't fully understand it.

[image]

From the schema, i think that party role is a tree-structure table? A role can have a parent role? Example: CEO > Head of Development > Developer

Or, party roles are organized in categories, like in the picture? Person Role, Customer, Organization Role.

I have tried to create the DB schema for this picture, and this is what i have:

[image]

And the data would look like this

```
Party                       
John Smith (Person)                     
Google (Organization)                       
Jane Smith (Person)                     


PartyRelationshipType                       
Employment                      
Married                     


PartyRole                       
Employer                        
Employee                        
Husband                     
Wife                        


PartyRelationship                       
Id          RelationshipType            FromParty           ToParty         Role            FromDate            ThruDate
1           Employment                  Google              John Smith      Employer        1/01/2008           16/08/2011
2           Married                     Jane Smith          John Smith      Wife            15/11/2000
```

Is the structure ok?

How can i define the relationships between Google employess for example? All of them they are employees, but at the same time they occupy different titles. Should i create a new Role for each title? or this data should be saved somewhere else?

Can somebody show me a real-data example?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to step back first and familiarise yourself with the notation, which seems to be Barker:

http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html

The Party Role structure does illustrate a hierarchy of a type, but each of the subtypes uses the same primary key, the Party Role ID.
Presumably, when implemented each of these entities would have varying attributes, so wouldn't be implemented as a single PartyRole table.  Also, there will be business rules of what other tables the party roles could relate to.
But in terms of Party Relationships, what you have seems correct